# Transparency on background image doesn't work

Tags: html, css, transparency

I am using a separate hover background image on my main navigation. The bottom half of the image hover background has a transparency of 50% (on the png file), but for some reason it is showing up as a milky white color instead of the flower image underneath it showing through the transparency. I don't know if this is related to my code or how the png is exported. Any help would be appreciated.

CSS:

```
#nav_1348933{
    position:relative;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style:none;
    height:115px;
    background: url(/_images/Layout/top-floral.png) no-repeat 0% 74%;
}

#nav_1348933 li a:hover{
    color: #fff;
    background: url(/_images/Layout/hover-tab.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

site: http://lltc.designangler.com

Comment: The "hover-tab.png" is not transparent...

Comment: The more I am looking into what is going on, it looks like it is related to the export settings for Fireworks.